# I cannot generate a token for a session_id that doesn't belong to api_key when implementing OpenTok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

I am trying to implement OpenTok in my rails 4 app, but I keep getting this error message:

```
Cannot generate token for a session_id that doesn't belong to api_key : 80056781
```

I followed the application trace, and the problem lies in the party method in the rooms controller.  Which can be seen below.

```
 def party
   @room = Room.find(params[:id])
   @tok_token = @opentok.generate_token :session_id => @room.sessionId
 end
```

It would be great if someone knew what the problem is.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which gem you are using...
Using [this opentok gem](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Ruby-SDK) you can implement this service:

```
class OpenTokService

  def initialize(room)
    @room = room
    @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new ENV["OPENTOK_API_KEY"], ENV["OPENTOK_API_SECRET"]
  end

  def generate_token
    create_session unless @room.session_id.present?
    role = :moderator #or :publisher
    @opentok.generate_token @room.session_id, {role: role}
  end

  def create_session
    tok_session = @opentok.create_session
    # save session_id on DB, Session never expires
    @room.update_attributes session_id: tok_session.session_id
  end

end
```

in your controller you can:

```
token = OpenTokService.new(@room).generate_token
```

Comment: Where does the OpenTokService class go? In place of my rooms controller?

Comment: you can put the service under: /yourapp/app/services/open_tok_service.rb

Comment: So do I have to make a service folder if I don't already have one? I am using rails

Comment: Put the class wherever you want. You cant put the class on lib folder or in a controller concern. I decide to put this kind of classes on a service folder.

Comment: Is there any documentation or sample apps that cover implementing this solution for rails apps?  I'm still having trouble.

Comment: No, it's only a class based on opetonk's gem documentation. There is not much to do from rails side. What problem you are having?

Comment: My routes are working etc..but I click on a link to a video chat the video windows don't display.  It must be a problem with the javascript, but I'm getting no errors